# One try with multiple catch blocks vs nested try

Tags: java, comparative-review, exception

I am creating program which will parse .csv file and I am using `FileReader` and `Scanner` classes from java API.

`FileReader` throws `FileNotFoundException`, `IOException`.

`Scanner`'s method `hasNextLine()` and `nextLine()` throw `IllegalStateException` and `NoSuchElementException`.

Should I use 1 *try* and 4 multiple *catch* blocks? Or *try* block nested in another *try* block(which has 2 *catch* blocks) with 2 *catch* blocks?

Code 1:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.lang.IllegalStateException;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (FileReader file = new FileReader("Doc.csv")) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
            }
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Code 2:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.lang.IllegalStateException;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (FileReader file = new FileReader("Doc.csv")) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
            try {
                while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                    System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
                }
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, I know that System.out.println(e) is not best practice for logging exception. So, please don't write about it

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Please note that unlike Stack Overflow, in order to give the best possible advice Code Review needs to look at concrete code in a real context. We also prefer general questions like "Any recommendations for how to improve this code in any way?" rather than specific questions about "How should I write my try-catch statement, A or B?" (where the correct answer often is C - as it was here as well). In this particular case I considered that you essentially have a complete example *project* here, so I'm letting this question pass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not going to handle each exception differently just use a multicatch:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (FileReader file = new FileReader("Doc.csv")) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
        }
    } catch (IllegalStateException | NoSuchElementException | IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

The `FileNotFoundException` is not catched since alternatives in a multi-catch statement cannot be related by subclassing (`FileNotFoundException` is a subclass of `IOException`).

Comment: Thanks. So, it is okey to have 1 try and catch(with multiple exceptions) block if I want to handle all exceptions with the same method?

Comment: this is what I meant by "do the same processing with all exceptions"